# Implement Rails Application using single front-end server(Apache) ,back-end server(Passenger) and database-server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

We have requirement to deploy rails application using single front-end server(Apache),two back-end server(Passenger) and two database-server.what will be the configuration? will it effect to change in rails application code base?

Comment: This line isn't clear - "two back-end server(Passenger) and two database-server." Can you provide more details?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki) to deploy to multiple servers at the same time. If you want more specific configuration help please ask one or more specific questions.